# Get last three chars of a json element in mySQL column

Tags: mysql

I have json data in a column called `settings`:

```json
{"AreaAdmin":null,
"StatsAreaAdmin":null,
"Logo":"1664805113094.svg",
"ExportFree":null,
"Banner":null,
"BannerMobile":null,
"BannerRetina":null,
"BannerAddr": null
}
```

I have figured out how to grab a json element:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.Logo")
```

How do I grab the last three chars of an element? I want to check if all `Logo` are `svg` or not. I've tried

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,"$.Logo"), LEN(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,"$.Logo")-1,3))
FROM `user`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.Logo")
```

But get
`Query 1 ERROR: FUNCTION uc_common.LEN does not exist`

Doing

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,"$.HQLogo"),3)
```

gives me `vg"`

Comment: `LEN` vs. `LENGTH`

Comment: *How do I grab the last three chars of an element?* What output do you need for shown JSON value? `'svg'`? use RIGHT(). `'094'`? Use SUBSTRING().

Answer (score 0):

I got it using

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,"$.Logo"),-4,3 )
FROM `user`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(settings, "$.Logo")
```

Comment: I think in your question you mistyped `$.HQLogo`

Comment: Also looking at the documentation of `SUBSTRING` and `RIGHT` it seems like `SUBSTRING(str, -3,3)` or `RIGHT(str, 3)` should work, don't know how it is working here maybe some end character is causing issue

Comment: Your query will return `'.sv'` - do you really need in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and test this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,'$.Logo')),3) FROM user;


+--------------------------------------------------------+
| RIGHT(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(settings,'$.Logo')),3) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| svg                                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```